# Error when try to add data to db in djnago app

Tags: django

i have djnago application (emergency notification system) and i see error when i try to add data to

this is my views py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Contact


####################################################

class Main(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'emnosys/main.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['css_file'] = 'styles.css'
        return context

###################################################



def Registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password1)
        myuser.save()

        return redirect('signin')
    return render(request, "emnosys/registration.html")

###############################################

def Signin(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['pass1']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password1)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "emnosys/main.html")
        else:
            return redirect('signin')
    return render(request, "emnosys/signin.html")

################################################

def Signout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

######################################################

class PersonalPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'emnosys/personalpage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['css_file'] = 'styles.css'
        return context

####################################################


def add_contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('about--username')
        message = request.POST.get('about--message')
        email = request.POST.get('about--email')
        Contact.objects.create(username=username, message=message, email=email)
    return render(request, 'emnosys/addcontacts.html')
```

this is my models py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class Contact(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=999, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=99, null=False)
```

this is my addcontacts html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/emnosys/css/addcontacts.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="about">
        <div class="label">
            Add contact
        </div>
        <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="username">
                <input name="about--username" id="about--username" placeholder=" " maxlength="40"></input>
                <label for="#about--username" id="username--label">Username for recipient (locally)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="textarea">
                <textarea name="about--textarea" id="about--textarea" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder=" " maxlength="999"></textarea>
                <label for="#about--textarea" id="textarea--label">Message</label>
            </div>
            <div class="telegram" id="telegram--label">
                <input name="about--email" id="about--email" placeholder=" " maxlength="40"></input>
                <label for="#about--email" id="email--label">Email of recipient (for example "qwerty@gmail.com")</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="waves">
        <img src="../../static/emnosys/images/waves.png" alt="">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i try to add new contact i write all data and see

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
     response = get_response(request)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\emnosys_wqrfl\emnosys\views.py", line 81, in add_contact
     Contact.objects.create(username=username, message=message, email=email)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
     obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 740, in save
     force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 778, in save_base
     force_update, using, update_fields,
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 881, in _save_table
     results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 921, in _do_insert
     using=using, raw=raw,
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_s
ql
     cursor.execute(sql, params)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
     return super().execute(sql, params)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wr
appers
     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
   File "D:\projects\EmNoSy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ERROR: Column "email" in table "emnosys_contact" does not exist
LINE 1: ...RT INTO "emnosys_contact" ("username", "message", "email") V...
                                                              ^
```

what to do, i will be very grateful if someone help me
i thought that error with migrations but it does not helped me

i made migrations and error is here yet

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace, the email field of your Contact class does not exist in your emnosys_contact table. You can solve it in any of the following ways:

1. You can manually add the email column to your table and run python manage.py makemigrations, then go back to your table and drop the email column you added then finally run python manage.py migrate. It should work now.
2. You can also try to comment out the email field in models.py, then run migrations. Afterwards, uncomment the email field and rerun migrations again.